# When counting toughness for a monster trophy, do you use the toughness when killed or the current toughness its type might have?

Tags: arkham-horror

There are a few parts to this question? First, if the toughness of a monster is reduced during combat by some effect such as a spell or item (I know there is one that reduces monster toughness by 1), is the trophy toughness also valued one less? I have been playing this as 'no'.

Second, if some effect raises the toughness of all or some monsters, and then after defeating one, the effect goes away, is the toughness of the trophy the originally listed toughess on the token or the enhanced toughness? Similarly one could imagine where a situation alters the toughness of a monster type you've already defeated.

I am not totally sure these last two cases actually exist but don't want to spoil more cards looking for it. If one could clarify that'd be great.

Comment: If I agree should I vote to have it be a duplicate, or should I take some other action?

Comment: It should be showing you a banner allowing you to agree and thus mark it as a duplicate as described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/133299 Is there something else you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe the banner doesn't show for mobile. I'll check it on desktop later.